# React-Redux _self usage

Tags: react-redux

is this a hack ? what I am doing with the _self variable to access these actions imported from my container and reach the reducer.. this is because I noticed I can't access my this.props in the handleInputChange event.. how else should I call onChange and then the action in more of a redux fashion ? So fat that's the only way I made it work but I sense it's no good :-)

```
import * as React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

let _self;
class CountrySelection extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    _self = this;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <label htmlFor="country">select a country</label>
          <select defaultValue={this.props.selectedCountry} 
            id="country" onChange={this.handleInputChange}>
            {
              this.props.available.map(x =>
                <option key={x.code} value={x.code}>{x.name}</option>)
            }
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <label htmlFor="city">select a city</label>
          <select defaultValue={this.props.selectedCity} 
            id="city" onChange={this.handleCityChange}>
            {
              this.props.selectedCities.map(x =>
                <option key={x.name} value={x.name}>{x.name}</option>)
            }
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    _self.props.loadCities(value);
  }
  handleCityChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    _self.props.storeCity(value);
    const place = _self.props.selectedCities.filter(function(x) {
      return x.name == value;
    })[0];
    _self.props.showWeather(place.lat, place.lng);
  }
}

CountrySelection.propTypes = {
  available: PropTypes.array,
};

export default CountrySelection
```

Answer (score 0):

I found I should have used () => action(), lucky I got away calling just one action